# HTML clipboard fragment displays well in Chrome but not in MSIE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a HTML fragment file which was created by extracting the Windows CF_HTML clipboard data after having copied a web page (http://www.w3schools.com/) in MSIE to the clipboard. The HTML fragment source is located here:
http://pastebin.com/suJDw9tW
Now when I open this file in Chrome, it displays the web page perfectly with all images.
However, when I try to open it in MSIE, it first seems to crash MSIE or make it hang for about 5-10 seconds, then the page is displayed very badly and WITHOUT IMAGES although there is a BASE tag inside the HTML.
How do I need to change this HTML to make it display correctly in MSIE WITH IMAGES?

Comment: Document type declaration should be on the first line without any preceeding characters.

Comment: Why MSIE still doesn't allow anything before the document type declaration, while all other browsers have no problems with this and just ignore it?

Comment: @Teemu Write this as a solution, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document type declaration should be on the first line without *any* preceeding characters.

This probably provides more backwards compatibility with older versions of IE. Those are just quite widely used even today, unlike older versions of the other browsers.